# Enable click event when another checkbox is cheched

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need a jQuery function that does the following thing: for example, when `checkbox1` is checked, when I click on some other elements (with an id starting with `element-`) I could print the `id` of these elements in the console as follows:

```
$('#checkbox1').click(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $(document).on('click','[id^=element-]', function(e) {
            console.log(this.id);
        });
    } else {}
});
```

I tested this example and it's not working. I have not idea when I'm wrong.

Comment: console.log($(this).attr('id'))

Comment: In addition to @sTx's comment, make sure your code is wrapped in a `$(document).ready(function() {...})`.

Comment: looks like it works with `this.id` too - didn't know that :)

Comment: You should consider using classes instead of searching for ids starting with a certain string. It should be faster.

Comment: @sTx yep. `this` is a reference to the DOMElement that raised the event. Therefore you can call any property of that object, eg `id`, `dataset`, `classList` etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way to do this would be to invert your logic. That is to say, place the click handler on the required elements and within that check the state of the checkbox. Try this:

```js
$(document).on('click', '[id^="element-"]', function(e) {
  if ($('#checkbox1').is(':checked'))
    console.log(this.id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" />
  Check me!
</label>

<div>
  <button id="element-foo">Foo</button>
  <button id="element-bar">Bar</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested it out, and this will work for you

```js
$("input[id^=d]").on("click", function() {
    var id = $(this).prop("id");
    if ($("#c1").is(":checked")) {
        console.log(id);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Dogs <input id="c1" type="checkbox" />
Cats <input id="d1" type="checkbox" />
Zebras <input id="d2" type="checkbox" />
Rhinos <input id="e1" type="checkbox" />
```